# Selecting primary Internet connection in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet

There is a computer that has access to the Internet both via the local network and by a GSM modem. As far as I know, when both connections are active, the modem connection is the primary one and all data is transmitted by the modem.

Because of the fact that the slow modem connection is supposed to be used as a backup connection, I want Windows to use it only when the connection via LAN is unavailable. At the same time I want the GSM modem connection to be active constantly.

Is it possible to make Windows not use modem connection when there is a working LAN Internet connection?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Mariusz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XP go to control panel and open network connetions.
From the top file menu select advanced and then advanced setting from the Menu.
You should see a box as below.

[image]

If your local Area Connection is above the [remote access connections} then Windows should access the LAN connection first.

You may also want to check the Provider Order.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When commenting Leon's answer I thought the connections box at the top of the window should contain all dial-up connections separately. Thank you very much for a clear explanation.

Comment: The 'advanced' menu option is actually a top-level menu item (located to the right of 'Tools'), and not located under the 'File' menu. Just adding this here since I had problems finding it.

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel, open the Network Connections.

Then click Advanced, Advanced Settings...

Here you would be able to set the connection priority.  Move your LAN connection to the top

Comment: Thanks for the clue, but unfortunately that window shows only wireless and cable connections. No dial-up connections are listed there :(. The thing is that I want to set the cable or wireless connection a higher priority than the dial-up modem connection.